# Using electron-usb with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp

I tried is to include `electron-usb` library into my electron-project.

When I execute `npm start` with `require('electron-usb')` in my `index.html` file an error occurs in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\electron-quick-start-master\electron-quick-start-master\node_modules\electron-usb\build\Release\electron-v0.36-win32-x64\usb_bindings.node
```

This error occurs in the file ELECTRON_ASAR.js
[Click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w65T.jpg)

What did I do wrong? I assume I have to somehow configure the module therewith it works with electron but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem last year. I solved it and use electron everyday to access various USB devices.

my solution is to use current version of electron-usb with electron-prebuilt@1.0.2 
It must be that version or lower. Reason is older versions of electron uses node ver 5.x.  Electron-usb does not work with Node greater than ver 5.x. It sucks cause I would like to use the newest features of latest Electron and node 7.

When I started this project a couple of years ago there was exactly zero info on the subject. I know how frustrating it can be. I Will be glad to help you getting started if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a wrong Electron version (see this issue for a similar problem: [kinect2](https://github.com/wouterverweirder/kinect2/issues/21))

Basically you should try compiling and running with the build script default version.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I tried it but unfortunately the error is still the same. Any other option?