# How do I access USB with Electron?

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, electron, node-gyp

*My systemenvironment: Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 (including C++ Compiler Tools) and node.js installed*

I tried to include a node library into the electon-quick-start-project and failed.

First of all I tried electron-usb to include electron-usb. [You can found my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621113/using-electron-usb-with-electron). Unfortunately I couldn't solve it.

Therefore I tried to include usb. I found help how to do this [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/use-node-usb-inside-electron/16748/3)
I did every step according to this description:

- npm install --save usb
- changing the variables property in the node_modules/usb/binding.gyp to include module_name and module_path
- electron-gyp node-gyp rebuild --target=0.26.0 --arch=ia32 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell

When I executed the rebuild command, I got a build error:  **error C2011: 'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition (compiling source file ..\libusb\libusb\core.c)**. Always the same error in different files.

I included HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC in the project-files. But it didn't work either afterwards.

Now I ask myself, what is the easiest and best way to access USB with Electron? Which library can you recommend? Do you know any complete tutorial to include this library into electron?

Answer (score 0):

if you have VS2015 installed on a windows 10 PC you shouldn't have to compile the source to electron-usb. just npm install then require it to use it.
after installing electron-usb you need to npm install electron-prebuilt@1.0.2  Must be that version because electron-usb doesn't work with Node version greater than 5.x.